# Can I replace a few query into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some query call and I want to replace it into one but I don't know it is possible. My database looks like:

[image]

My database calls:

```
$minbet = $mysql->query('SELECT `value` FROM `jackpot1_info` WHERE `name`="minbet"')->fetch_assoc();
$minbet =  $minbet['value'];

$maxbet = $mysql->query('SELECT `value` FROM `jackpot1_info` WHERE `name`="maxbet"')->fetch_assoc();
$maxbet =  $maxbet['value'];

$maxitems = $mysql->query('SELECT `value` FROM `jackpot1_info` WHERE `name`="maxitems"')->fetch_assoc();
$maxitems =  $maxitems['value'];

$maxitemsinpot = $mysql->query('SELECT `value` FROM `jackpot1_info` WHERE `name`="maxitemsinpot"')->fetch_assoc();
$maxitemsinpot =  $maxitemsinpot['value'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, just select `name` and `value` in a single query and you will have each `name` and `value` pair in a separate row:

```
$select = $mysql->query('
    SELECT `name`, `value`
    FROM `jackpot1_info`
    WHERE `name` IN ("minbet","maxbet","maxitemsinpot","maxitems")
');

while ($result = $mysql->fetch_assoc())
{
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Output would look like:

```
array(2) {
  'name' =>
  string(12884901894) "minbet"
  'value' =>
  int(123)
}

array(2) {
  'name' =>
  string(12884901894) "maxbet"
  'value' =>
  int(456)
}

...
```

I'm sure you can do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` instead of `=` for one query.

```
$select = $mysql->query('SELECT name,value FROM `jackpot1_info` WHERE `name` IN ("minbet","maxbet","maxitemsinpot","maxitems")');
$result = $mysql->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: @RuchishParikh That somehow doesn't make a sense. You're selecting the `value` column, but you're trying to read the `maxbet` column out of the results (which is not there obviously).

Comment: Still, using your code, he won't be able to distinguish which value belongs to which name, he'll get just a bunch of values. I personally wonder why this answer has two up-votes since the first version didn't work at all and the second version doesn't help to solve OP's problem.